# Recursively count inheritance in Python

Tags: python

I need to implement a function that counts the number of inheritance recursively in a given Python class.

For instance, if class A inherits from B and C, and B inherits from D, then the number of inheritances of A is 2; this is because A inherits from B, and C (first level) and B, in turn, inherits from D (second level) (Is a sort of indirect inheritance)

I write the following snippet of code:

```
def search_inherited_classes(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            if line.startswith("class") and "(" in line:
                class_name = line.split(" ")[1].split("(")[0]
                base_class = line.split("(")[1].split(")")[0].strip()
                if base_class and base_class != "object":
                    if base_class in count:
                        count[base_class] += 1
                    else:
                        count[base_class] = 1

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            search_inherited_classes(os.path.join(root, file))

return count
```

However, the snippet only extracts the first level of inheritance.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You might consider parsing the code using an AST ([example](https://www.mattlayman.com/blog/2018/decipher-python-ast/)).

Comment: so you decided to count an inheritance depth by parsing text of `.py` file? Imagine that I have class `A` in `file_1.py` and its parent `B` is in `file_2.py` ... and class `B` has inner nonpublic class `C` in its body

Comment: What's the usecase? Maybe using `__mro__` would be helpful...

Comment: If you really need to do that with static analysis, by checking the source files, as you are doing, there is no simple way to get it right - if you need correct behavior it would be easier to pig-back on another static source analysis tool, such as mypy, and write a plug-in that would do what you need.

However, if you are allowed to import the modules "live", just checking `len(A.__mro__)` will give you the correct desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ast`it allows you to inspect and manipulate the code structure in a higher level of abstraction.

for your specific case try the following.

```py
import ast

def count_inheritance(node):
    count = 0
    for subclass in node.body:
        if isinstance(subclass, ast.ClassDef):
            count += 1
            if subclass.bases:
                for base in subclass.bases:
                    count += count_inheritance(base)
    return count

def search_inherited_classes(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        code = file.read()
        tree = ast.parse(code)
        count = 0
        for node in ast.walk(tree):
            if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef):
                count += count_inheritance(node)
    return count
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. However, I need to pass to the function the entire project (e.g., "home/desktop/pythonProject"). In this case, the snippet analyzes a single python file (I tried to run your code on a single python file, and I received 0 as the return value, although the file contained a class with that inherited by another class (in a different file)